# Facing Connection timeout in EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, httpconnection

Right now, we migrated 1 EC2 machine under private Subnet. And, another service which we are using is outside subnet. But after this migration, all time consuming calls are in stuck state.

Previously, everything was working fine, when all are in public subnet.

I checked dependent service logs, and I got to know that, another service is able to process my service request. And, returns 200 HTTP response. But, my service is not able to receive this.

It seems like, HTTP connection got lost in between because of long time.

Can you please suggest me the solution, how can I overcome from this problem.

Infrastructure - AWS EC2, AWS VPC.

Update 1-

When I ran netstat command. Below are the output-

**Situation After migration**

ubuntu@ip-172-30-3-57:~$ netstat -tn 2>/dev/null

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp6       0      0 172.30.3.57:42808       54.149.126.223:8080     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       1      0 172.30.3.57:42807       54.149.126.223:8080     CLOSE_WAIT

**Situation before migration**

ubuntu@ip-172-30-5-225:~/old_azkaban/azkaban-web-server$ netstat -tn 2>/dev/null
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp6       0      0 172.30.5.197:52416      54.149.126.223:8080     ESTABLISHED

tcp6       0      0 172.30.5.197:52415      54.149.126.223:8080     ESTABLISHED

And, meaning of state-

ESTABLISHED
          The socket has an established connection.

CLOSE_WAIT
          The remote end has shut down, waiting for the socket to close.

Comment: Are you trying to access EC2 instance outside of VPC?

Comment: My service is running on EC2. We are using same VPC for the whole organisation machines. My service is under private subnet. Service that we calling is outside subnet.

Comment: What does the EC2 instance do -- what are the "time consuming calls" that it makes? Does your EC2 instance communicate outside the VPC? And if so do you have a NAT instance in a public subnet and a route for your private subnet to use the NAT?

Comment: We have some other service inside VPC but in different subnet, that is taking 2-3 hrs time to process request. And, my service is doing sync call to that service.

Comment: If you want to access a server, try telnet the port. If you can't reach, check your Routing tables, Security groups, subnet ACLs. Are you coming from the same VPC?

Comment: @devsda For my confirmation, Your service is running on EC2(source) in different subnet. This service calling to EC2 instance(target) in private subnet both in same VPC.

Comment: @devsda  In target instance, you open traffic for source instance in security group. For adding rule, which port your service can communicate you open it then in IP address part add your source's private ip address.

Comment: @KumareshBabu One more point, I tried to hit other service with curl command, and its working fine. It means, its not an issue of access of port.
The issue arises only when the call is time consuming, and e have to wait for that.

Comment: @devsda It seems your EC2 Instance performance is not good to communicate with services
correct?

Comment: It is happening with all the migrated machines.

Comment: @devsda Can you check the CPUUtilization of your EC2 instances in AWS CloudWatch metrics tab. If it is high then it is performance issue.